# Disable ExtJs requests aggregation

Tags: extjs, ext-direct

When I use ExtJs & ExtDirect I see in debug that requests to server which are close in time, are aggregated into one request which is then split in the server.

As this is probably very good for performance, it makes it difficult for debugging.

Can I somehow disable this feature?

Answer (score 0):

Set `enableBuffer: false` on the provider. Docs [here](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.2-classic/#!/api/Ext.direct.RemotingProvider-cfg-enableBuffer).